# Hide a div on load and showing it on hover of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, hide

I have a div that have img with id and another div inside it
I want to hide the info div (you can see in code) on load of the page and then show it again on hover of the img - I also want the info div to slide right nicely.. 
Thanks in advance for helping :)

the HTML

```
        <div class="wrapper">
        <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
            <div id="info">
                info- blah <br> 
                blah &amp; blah .<br>
                email@gmail.com
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS

```
.wrapper{
float: left;
opacity: 0.4;
margin-top: -30px;
margin-left: 5px;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  }
#logo {
        width: 39px;
}
.wrapper:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
#info {
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float:right;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

What is the jQuery I need for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AW9qh/ like that?

Comment: The reason that this is being down voted is because there are already a vast array of answered questions related to this topic on this site. That's what makes SO awesome, it's a living interactive wiki of problems people are having in the wild. Not a place where you have people code for you. Before asking a question think, what is my problem? Lets see if others have had a problem similar. In your case the answer is most certainly yes.

Comment: And rather than writing code for you to farm SO points on an easy question the *real* answer here is to tell you to look into CSS syntax & structure, specifically pseudo-selectors. The concept is very straight forward and after reading a bit you will be able to easily answer your own question.

Comment: thanks Swordfish for that but I've tried to find an answer first but I couldn't  really find the thing I'm looking for.. I'll be sure to check pseudo-selectors. (I really am a beginner so there for the ignorance =])

Comment: For sure, and I'm not trying to detract you from asking questions. But trying to stear you I. The right direction for not only your current problem, but for problems you will run into in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.
I don't know if that's what you wanted, but since you're already using CSS3, you don't need jQuery for that:

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
}
.wrapper:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
#info {
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float:right;
    font-size: 9px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.wrapper:hover #info {
    left:100%;
    opacity:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2B2v/

Comment: both of your comments helped (though Andy's comment was more the effect I was looking for) But also both of them made the position of the div changed...

Answer (score 0):

Place your `.wrapper` with the same image height. Place an `overflow:hidden` to hide text which is under.

After you must just change height in .wrapper:hover to show the text.

If you want a nice transition, you can adjust that with

```
.wrapper:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    height:100px;
    transition: height 1;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari */
}
```

like this : http://jsfiddle.net/AW9qh/2/